# DLOOKUP returning #NAME? error in IIF statement

Tags: ms-access, textbox, ms-access-2013

I have a form I am using to report back data from a table. For my text box control, I have to use DLOOKUP to display the value I want, otherwise it displays the index number. Here is the code I have for the text box, which does display the value:

```
DLookUp("[FORMATION_NAME]","R_FORMATIONS","[FORM_ID]=" & [FIRST_FRM_FK])
```

So far, so good. The problem I'm having now is that if there is a null value, DLOOKUP returns an #Error code.

I found a solution using an IIF statement and ISNULL:

```
IIf(IsNull([WELL_MASTER]![FIRST_FRM_FK]),"",DLookUp("[FORMATION_NAME]","R_FORMATIONS","[FORM_ID]=" & [FIRST_FRM_FK]))
```

When I try this out in a query, it works great; however, when I put the expression in my text box control, DLOOKUP returns a #Name error.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this? Google foo is failing me again.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

Okay, I've tried the following:

Per Minty: `Nz(DLookUp("[FORMATION_NAME]","R_FORMATIONS","[FORM_ID]=" & [FIRST_FRM_FK]),0)`

DLookup function part works, but nulls return as #Error.

Per Kostas K:  `Nz(DLookUp("FORMATION_NAME","R_FORMATIONS","[FORM_ID]=" & [FIRST_FRM_FK]),0)`

Same as Minty's suggestion.

Wrapped in an IIF statement using Is Null versus ISNULL function:

```
IIf([WELL_MASTER]![FIRST_FRM_FK] Is Null,"",DLookUp("[FORMATION_NAME]","R_FORMATIONS","[FORM_ID]=" & [FIRST_FRM_FK]))
```

I'm back to my original problem of the DLookup function returning a #Name error.

Here is the weird thing--the IIF statement expressions work if they are in a query. It is when I copy the expression to a textbox control that the DLookup fails. The DLookup function works fine in a textbox expression as long as nothing is wrapped around it. The minute you put it inside of an IIF statement, it stops working.

Any thoughts on what it is about the textbox control it is not liking?

Thank you Minty and Kostas K for trying to help me figure this out. :)

Comment: If this is a lookup field you could use a combo box to display the value directly. Alternatively use the Nz() function `Nz(DLookUp("[FORMATION_NAME]","R_FORMATIONS","[FORM_ID]=" & [FIRST_FRM_FK]),0)`

Comment: Thanks, Minty! Can't use a combo box for this, but your Nz function worked. I had tried this one previously, but must have not had it structured correctly.

Comment: Darn! I thought it worked, but when I looked at my test record in the table, there was a 0 in the test null field. I cleared it out and looked at it again in the form and am getting the #Error message. The DLookup portion is working but the NZ part is not working. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Remove the `[]` brackets from `FORMATION_NAME`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Nz() function

```
Nz(DLookUp("[FORMATION_NAME]","R_FORMATIONS","[FORM_ID]=" & [FIRST_FRM_FK]),0)
```

Comment: Didn't work. I thought it did at first, but no such luck.

Comment: I would probably just put the data directly into the forms underlying query. Use a left join and you should still be able to edit the data on the form if required.

Comment: It is already in the underlying query. The problem is that it is a foreign key tying back to a reference table. If I could use a combo box, I could just specify the column count, but that option is not available for text boxes, and this has to be in a text box.

Comment: Then join the reference table to the FK stored in you main table and pull in the text from that. Then display it not the FK.

Comment: I have 3 columns in the main table that reference back to the same reference table. I can add and join the reference table to the main table for one column, but joining the tables for all three columns returns no results and adding the reference table 2 more times and joining each column to one reference table returns no results. This was why I ended up going the DLookup route.

Comment: Minty, I finally found part of an answer to this problem. If I put the Nz function around just the last column, the expression will work. Here is what I came up with: `=DLookUp("[FORMATION_NAME]","R_FORMATIONS","[FORM_ID]=" & Nz([FIRST_FRM_FK],0))` This resolves my first problem, but I'm still having the same issue (not involving nulls this time) using a DLOOKUP with a SWITCH function on another textbox. Thank you though for helping me with this.

Comment: Glad you sorted it - If you use an left join with each copy of the reference table and the NZ function you can cover all the bases..